# Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync not Available in .net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I didn't find Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync in .net core Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational namespace. I added the reference as below.

[image]

Please help for this reference issue.

Comment: From this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlcommandasync?view=efcore-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=efcore-5.0), It seems that EF core does not support this , You can refer to this [link](https://www.michalbialecki.com/en/2020/09/14/executing-raw-sql-with-entity-framework-core-5/) to learn how to execute sql in ef core 5

Comment: I found that in .net core 5 available functions are ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync and ExecuteSqlRawAsync for running sql commands